# Anyone heard of this site and was it safe?

Tags: malware, virus, websites

I was browsing a [reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/MrRobot/comments/3gzesc/mrrobot_elliots_home_computer_wallpaper/) and found a strange link to what it looked to be a image hosting site that I've never heard of http://imgh.us/elliotwp1.jpg.

I clicked the link and it said "404 not found". This made me curious and I started looking around to try to see if I could find anything on this site. I got nothing, no reviews, articles, nothing. All I found was a reddit page saying it was going to be shut down in which no one responded to whatsoever. I also saw that there were quite a few images that were using this domain. I entered the URL on virus total and two engines said it was malicious and one said suspicious.

[image: Screenshot 1]

I understand that when a 404 is displayed it means that the server is running, it just couldn't find that link or content I was looking for.

Why would the servers be up if it was shut down in the past?

I'm kinda worried that that link or site may have been malicious and my browser might be compromised. I'm running Linux so I know that it if it was malicious that it probably wouldn't be able to do much. I have no idea, I'm probably just being really paranoid. Anyways, let me know what you guys think about this, and tell me if you've heard of this site.

Comment: You could always do a whois lookup on the URL and try and contact the owner, asking about the site and possibly informing him/her of the reddit post.

Comment: I'm not sure this question isn't too localized to be a good fit for the site, but this is possibly related: https://twitter.com/SwiftOnSecurity/status/927954847227367424

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirusTotal inspects the *files* served by a website. If you look at the main [analysis page](https://www.virustotal.com/#/domain/imgh.us) you will see different scores for different files. This is not surprising as it is a file hosting site. The site itself might be fine, it's the files that are the problem.

[This page](http://archiveteam.org/index.php?title=Imgh.us) lists the shutdown notice you refer to. The domain is still valid until: `Sat Sep 08 23:59:59 GMT 2018`.

Why it is still active is anyone's guess. The domain owner's email is listed on WHOIS, you could ask him.

All in all, there is nothing suspicious in any of this info.

Answer (score 0):

***Why would the servers be up if it was shut down in the past?***

There's a large number of reasons why a web admin would leave the servers up, that's near impossible to determine without contacting the administrator.

***I'm kind of worried my browser might be compromised.***

If you are interested in finding out if the website is malicious or if your browser has been compromised, you can use a packet sniffing program to examine the traffic between your computer and the website. Generally malicious websites will have some JavaScript code that will allow an attacker to do various things with your browser. Regardless, it's never a bad idea to run a virus scan. =)